# set a default tablespace for a mysql database?

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to specify a default tablespace for a MySQL database? I'd like to have most of my databases on a magnetic disk, but there's one that I want to stay on an SSD.

I understand that I could do it with "create table...on tablespace", but I'm hoping that I can just tell MySQL "everthing for database X goes over here..."  Especially because I'm loading this database from a dump, and the dumpfile is too big to edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just guess this is on Linux. In this case: Why don't you just mount your SSD partition to the mysql-directory where the database will be put?

e. g:

```
mount /path/to/SSDpartition /var/lib/mysql/databasename
```

This way, MySQL won't have to care about all the partition and tablespace stuff, instead your underlying filesystem mounts will take care of this.

If the SSD partition you want to use is /dev/sdc1 and is not mounted yet, you could use:

```
mount /dev/sdc1 /var/lib/mysql/databasename
```

If it's already mounted to e.g. /SSD and you just want to use the directory /SSD/mysql for your database, you could use

```
mount -o bind /dev/SSD/mysql /var/lib/mysql/databasename
```

Another option would be to use a symlink:

```
ln -s /dev/SSD/mysql /var/lib/mysql/databasename
```

Comment: I ended up just using the symlink.  Sometimes the solution is simpler than I think!  thanks!